# C# using MYSQL ExecuteScalar() type error

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin

I am using the MySQL library in Xamarin to connect to my database. I am calling the `ExecuteScalar()` command to check if a user exists in my DB.

I cast the return of `ExecuteScalar()`  to an Int32 and storing in a Int32 variable called `userCount`, but Visual Studio is throwing a `cast is not valid` error when I try to call `(int32)checkUser.ExecuteScalar();`

This is how it suggested to be done in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx), so I am confused. Here is my code:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

MySqlCommand checkUser = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <MyCoolDatabase> WHERE Userid = '" + username + "'", connection);

Int32 userCount = (Int32)checkUser.ExecuteScalar(); //error is here
if(userCount >0)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Did you debug and see that type is returned by the `ExecuteScalar`?

Comment: it sounds like it's returning a null and that's why the cast is failing

Comment: Are you sure you are not returning null?  By the way, the documentation is at this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I will test if I am being returned null now

Comment: `Int32 userCount = (int)(long)checkUser.ExecuteScalar();` Count under MySql returns an Int64.

Comment: Looks to be that this will be a _type mismatch_ error, the `WHERE` column looks like it would be of a numeric type, and the (sic) inline variable is going to be a string `WHERE Userid = '" + username + "'"`

Comment: What is the actual error message? Post the *full* exception, not a substring from the message. As it is, it's impossible to guess whether MySQL complained or you tried to cast a long to an int. `Int32` is an int

Comment: @BarneyChambers you can find the actual result type by examining the result value in the debugger. Just store it to a temporary variable and add it as a watch, or hover over it. The debugger will show the value *and* actual type.

Comment: @BarneyChambers you should also *fix* the query and use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

You linked to `System.Data.SqlClient` and not `MySQL.Data.MySqlClient`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html

There is an example there -

```
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (result != null)
        {
            int r = Convert.ToInt32(result);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of countries in the world database is: " + r);
        }
```

Likely you are trying to cast `null` to `int32`

Comment: No, the problem is result is a `long`, as it's boxed inside an `object` it can't be converted directly to `int32`.

Comment: `SELECT Count(*)` will always return a long >= 0, never a `null`, Any error would throw an _Exception_

Comment: `Convert` isn't going to work when the cast fails *unless* the input is a string which results in a call to `Int32.Parse()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just simply provided the documentation for this call from the MySql documentation.  Not sure why the downvote.

Comment: It makes me an error that 'Value is too big or too small. cannot convert to int32'

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem few weeks ago.
The problem is that `ExecuteScalar()` return **long object** and it cant be simple converted to int. but it can be cast **to long** and **then to int**.

Change you code from:

```
Int32 userCount = (Int32)checkUser.ExecuteScalar(); //error is here
```

To:

```
int userCount = (int)(long)(checkUser.ExecuteScalar());
```

This works for me without any problem.

---

Btw there is full solution how to work with parametres:

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <MyCoolDatabase> WHERE Userid = @user";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", username);

    int userCount = (int)(long)(checkUser.ExecuteScalar());
    if (userCount > 0)
    {
        //work
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course it can! `ExecuteScalar` returns *any* result *wrapped* as an object which you can cast to the appropriate type. If you had a problem, it's because the return type was *not* an `int`. Had you tried to cast to a `long` you probably wouldn't have any issues. It's easy to find the proper type - just inspect the contents of the result in the debugger

Comment: To put it another way - people always cast the results of `ExecuteScalar()` since .NET 1.0 came out. If there was a need to convert to string, someone would have noticed these 15 years.

Comment: But you definitly cant just write `(int)ExecuteScalar()` As you said you have to cast to long and then to int. I have updated the answer.

Comment: No. If the type is int, you need to cast to int. If it's long, you need to cast to long and use that long. If the type is long, *why* do you think you can safely cast to int without throwing? Or that you can parse the equivalent string? What if the number is over the maximum int?

Comment: Results of Mysql count is long independents if number is 5 or bigger than Int32.max and the @Barney Chambers in question wants to store result in int variable so thats reason why another cast to int. Another thing is that this query should be always only 0 or 1 so you dont have to worry about limits.